# I need a way to search across all of the StackExchange vertical communities. Does this exist?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search, stack-exchange

Maybe I'm too dense to find it. It sure would be HANDY!

Comment: I believe this should be the default search!  It would reduce cross posting and increase availability of answers!

Answer (score 4):

Implemented at http://stackexchange.com.

[image: Search on Stack Exchange]

Answer (score 2):

**On Google:**

> [word] AND (site:stackexchange.com OR
>   site:stackoverflow.com)

Note: the results appear for the first site and then the second, so for a large search you many never get to the second.