# Search for which Stack Exchange site to use

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, search

I would like to be able to search on the Stack Exchange gateway for a subject and get a list of the most relevant sites (possibly Google instant style, filtering the normal list). Searching is often a lot faster than scrolling through a list, and this one is growing all of the time. If there are several similar sites it could also help seeing the difference without reading through several FAQs first. This could be a good answer to "where should I post this question?".

The search should probably be based more on the tags and the site FAQ/description then on the actual questions.

Comment: I have a feeling this would cause more harm than good. Some people would take the tool's recommendation as a proof that their off-topic question was wrongly closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but Stack Exchange already has a `search` feature which searches all Stack Exchange sites. This should give you a good idea where to post your subject.

Here's [an answer with a helpful image](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66932/225020) by Jeff.

---

But wait, there is more.

To fine-tune the search, you can set up [a filter on Stack Exchange site](https://stackexchange.com/filters) ([tag-filters](/questions/tagged/tag-filters) here corresponds to this feature) to limit which sites and which tags (among other conditions) are searched.

Answer (score 0):

Since all of the Stack Exchange sites are all on one page in the [sites list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#name) you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for the terms you are looking for. However, your keywords might not be found. So you will have to use other similar search terms manually, instead of with the help of a search engine, to find out where questions should be asked.